# Getting values from 2 sets of data from JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am parsing data from a json file and converting to a HTML table, this is done, but I have 2 sets of data in the JSON file. The second one is to get the direct value. I dunno where i am doing wrong, is the JSON format or the the way i am trying to get the values. Can anybody guide me on how to achieve this ??

//Json File  format

> { "posts":  [ { "title":"12",
>   "answer":"55.5" }, { "title":"123",
>   "answer":"66.6" },] "author": [ {
>   "book":"12", "date":"55.5" },] }

// Script

```
$.getJSON("wc.json",function(data)
{
alert(author.book);
alert(author.date);
$.each(data.posts, function(i,data)
{
var faqs =
"<tr><td>"+data.title+"</td><td>"+data.answer+"</td></tr>";
$(faqs).appendTo("#faq tbody");
});
}
);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON format you have has syntactic errors.  Try this:

HTML:

```
<table id="faq"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Script:

```
var data = { 
"posts": [ { "title":"12", "answer":"55.5" },
           { "title":"123", "answer":"66.6" }],
"author": [ {"book":"12", "date":"55.5" }] }


$.each(data.posts, function(i,data)
{
  var faqs =
  "<tr><td>"+data.title+"</td><td>"+data.answer+"</td></tr>";
  $(faqs).appendTo("#faq tbody");
});
```

BTW, the author key is set to an array which needs to be accessed in an array: author[0].book in the alerts.

Comment: Trailing commas are now allowed in ECMAScript 5 for objects and arrays: http://ryanalberts.com/?p=283.  So the JSON format you have will work in newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rename the array value in the nested each, then call the property against that, like so:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i,post){
  var faqs = "<tr><td>"+post.title+"</td><td>"+post.answer+"</td></tr>";
  $(faqs).appendTo("#faq tbody");
});
```

hth
Theo